# How to conditional build python package with selected modules

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible in Python to conditionally build a pip package with selected modules?

Example Scenario - I have a system that has logic for different operating systems, to reduce final package size, I am thinking if there is a way to have a build script that includes only required packages based on some configuration file for each operating system and exclude all others.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible I would rather recommend splitting your project into multiple projects:

- main project containing the platform independent code
- one dependency project per platform for the platform dependent code

The `setup.cfg` of the main project could look like this:

```
# ...
[options]
install_requires =
    my_package_win ; platform_system=="Windows"
    my_package_linux ; platform_system=="Linux"
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58930304/11138259

Comment: Thank you! this is what exactly I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`--no-deps`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps). You can have a script determine what the OS is and generate a list of packages that would need to be installed, the iterate over that list and install them with `--no-deps`.